# How make a filter "does not contain" in Google Stackdriver logs

Tags: logging, string-comparison, google-cloud-stackdriver

In Google Stackdriver advanced filter I can insert something like:

```
resource.type="container"
resource.labels.cluster_name="mycluster"
textPayload!="Metric stackdriver_sink_successfully_sent_entry_count was not found in the cache."
severity="INFO"
textPayload:(helloworld)
```

The last rule means that the field *textPayload* should contain the string *helloworld*. 
But I'm not able to find a way to add a NOT operator.

I would use something like:

```
textPayload:!(helloworld)
```

but doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)", "[mre]" and their linked pages. Please explain what "doesn't work" mean in detail.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

just add AND NOT between two rows:

```
resource.type="container"
resource.labels.cluster_name="mycluster"
textPayload!="Metric stackdriver_sink_successfully_sent_entry_count was not found in the cache."
severity="INFO" AND NOT
textPayload:(helloworld)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is but for me I had to prefix the textPayload with a tilde like `~textPayload:" text I dont want"` for it to work

Answer (score 16):

You can use the filter`-text:unicorn` if you want to exclude entries containing the word "unicorn"

Source: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/basic-filters

Comment: just fyi, this works. But if you try to create a metric with the same query and then see it in the metric explorer, it shows "Selected metric is invalid." error. So @suikoy's answer might work better for those who use log based metrics

Answer (score 0):

There is sometimes `\n` at the end by the way.

Also you can click on log, click sub entry and clik hide.